# Удобная IDE для веб разработчика Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ide, ftp, веб-программирование

Подскажите удобную IDE для веб разработчика на Ubuntu. Главное требование быстрое подключение по FTP и правка там файлов (+ emmet и подсветка SCSS). В аналогии с Windows удобно было пользоваться (в плане работы с FTP) - PhpDesigner ну и класика Notepad++. Может я не полностю разобрался в NetBins и PhpShtorm но там как то по другому с выгрузкой проекта  на FTP и работой с файлами

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вначале я даже не понял, что именно нужно редактировать, но потом прояснилось - веб. В линуксе принята немного другая политика - тут одна утилита для одной вещи. Поэтому, редактор должен уметь редактировать код, а не лазить ещё и по ftp. Поэтому, разобем задачу на две - ftp и редактор.

**FTP**

тут все очень просто. Делаете себе папку где удобно и монтируете удаленный ftp себе. Для этого есть различные средства, например, [curlftpfs](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_ftp) и [статья на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/85084/) как им пользоваться.

Многие хостинги не дают ftp, а дают ssh доступ. И тут также есть подобное решение - [sshfs](http://www.openkazan.info/sshfs-mount-remote-directories-ssh-ubuntu-linux).

Такой способ дает кучу приимуществ. Файлы оказываются как бы локально. Работают все (практически) консольные (и не только) утилиты. Только скорость иногда чуточку мендленее. И в такую папку можно будет зайти даже "проводником" (наутилус или кто там сейчас в убунте).

Если лень каждый раз все вбивать ручками, можно сделать скрипт, который будет монтировать и размонтировать по одной команде.

**Редактор**

Есть шутка, что существует всего два редактора - вим и эмакс, а все остальное - это не редакторы (а IDE, к примеру).

Приимущества вима в том, что обычно он есть везде. Даже на древних роутерах. И если нужно в конфиге поправить одну строку, то он самое простое решение (зашел по ssh, поправил и готово).

Если Вам нравится notepad++, то рекомендую посмотреть на gedit (как простенький блокнот, есть в репозитриях), geany (чуть навороченее, есть в репозитриях), sublime (хорош, но немного платен), atom (навороченный, думаю, там и к ftp есть встроенный доступ, но как по мне, тяжеловат).

Или использовать его духовного наследника [NotepadQQ](http://notepadqq.altervista.org/wp/). Есть официальный `ppa`, который добавляется через `sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:notepadqq-team/notepadqq`. Ну а дальше классика: `sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude -y install notepadqq`.

**P.S.**

Думаю, стоит попробовать с [atom](https://atom.io/) и посмотреть на плагины.

Посмотрел, первые попавшие плагины - [remote-ftp](https://atom.io/packages/remote-ftp) и [remote-edit](https://atom.io/packages/remote-edit) похоже решают проблему.